# Is it possible to periodially refresh a whiptail dialog?

Tags: linux, whiptail

I have a whipail dialog where I display a dashboard:

```bash
source ../script/includes/tasks

pick_task () {
    local options=(
        "$LOGS_TASK" "Check the logs of a service"
        "$KILL_TASK" "Kills a service"
        "$KILL_ALL_TASK" "Kills all services"
        "$SELECT_TASK" "Allows you to select the services you want to run" 
    )

    local menu_height="${#options[@]}"
    local dialog_height=$((menu_height + 9))
    local dialog_width=80

    result=$(whiptail --title "Dashboard" --menu "What do you want to do?" "$dialog_height" "$dialog_width" "$menu_height" "${options[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
    echo $result
}
```

This works fine but I'd like to also display some additional information in this window that dynamically refreshes. Is it possible to refresh this dialog while it is open?

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to have 2 or more commands being presented in the same terminal is to use a multiplexor such as `tmux`. For example, giving the command:

```bash
tmux new-session -s mysession 'watch -n 1 date' \
   ';' split-window -v -p 50 -t 0 './myscript'
```

in the terminal will split it (vertically, `-v`) into 2 equal halves (50%, `-p 50`), and run the `watch` command in the top, and a script, `myscript` in the bottom half. This latter would be based on your current script. For a simple test:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
result=$(whiptail --menu text 10 40 3 taga a tagb bb tagc ccc 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
tmux kill-session
```

Note the quoted semi-colon (`';'`) as it is an argument to `tmux`, not to the shell.
Since the result is obtained in a sub-shell, you may need to pass it back through a temporary file.
But you could also continue using further commands within tmux, creating and removing windows as your script progresses.